# Is there a database for fossilized coral reefs that have been reported?

Tags: marine-biology, database, ichthyology, research-tools, fossil

Given that coral lives only [up to 5,000 years](https://www.americanoceans.org/facts/age-of-coral-reefs/), and I assume marine biologists have maps of where all known living reefs are around the world for research and monitoring, where can I find information on locations of known dead coral, and especially *fossilized* coral as I [once encountered on an island](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/how-quickly-can-coral-fossilize) in the western Caribbean?

Is there a scientific database, oceanography software/framework, or perhaps publications such as by NCBI, which provide records of instances of fossilized coral which have been located and which perhaps document their age, conditions that led to their demise, etc.?

Comment: NOAA has a helpful short article called "What's in a Name? - Coral Reef" by John K. Reed which has a section on "Coral Growth and Reef Age" which was useful for finding references to more recently developed fossils: https://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/explorations/02sab/background/corals/corals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, have a read from:

The [Paleobiology](https://paleobiodb.org/#/) Database (PBDB): A comprehensive online resource that compiles data on fossil occurrences from various scientific publications and databases.

The [Ocean Biogeographic Information System](https://obis.org/) (OBIS): A global database that provides access to marine species occurrence data, including fossil corals.

Fossil forums and reddit fossil ID have direct access to pro geologists.

The [Fossilworks](http://www.fossilworks.org/) Database:  It aims to provide a comprehensive record of fossil species including corals from all ages.

Comment: Thank you. On OBIS how can you filter for fossil corals specifically?

Comment: Perhaps this:  https://obis.org/taxon/1292 https://obis.org/dataset/89e23fc8-3f61-4480-9de3-358fe6eefe0b